# RHEL 6 Upstart User Jobs

Tags: rhel6, upstart

Does RHEL6 support upstart user jobs?

I modified `/etc/dbus-1/system.d/Upstart.conf` and added a policy section for my username.  I then created `~/init.d/userjob.conf`.

When I do `inictrl list` it doesn't show up.

Does RHEL6 support this? If so how do I debug it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User jobs are supported from version 1.3 of Upstart.

See:
http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#user-job

RHEL6 (or CentOS 6) use version: 0.6.5.